# ls hard link question

Tags: directory, ls, hard-link

I run `ls -la` on the `Volumes` directory. It shows the `MM` dir to have 9 hard links and the `Media` dir to have 12. If I then `cd` to the `MM` directory and run `ls -la`, it shows only 7 items whereas if I `cd` to the `Media` dir, it has 12 as expected. Why does the `MM` dir have only 7 items? shouldn't it be 9?

Answer (score 1):

Every directory has at least two references:  one from its parent directory (the `Volumes` entry in `/`), and one from its own `.` entry.

If there are subdirectories, each has a `..` entry that refers back to the parent, and those also contribute toward the parent's link count.

So your `/Volumes` directory's link count of 9 consists of one from `/`, plus one from itself, plus 7 from subdirectories.

Comment: no it contains 7 including the "/." and "/.."

Answer (score 0):

`.` represents the current directory, where as `..` represents the parent directory.

For example, currently I am in `demo` directory

```
$cd demo/dir1
$pwd
/home/guru/demo/dir1       <-  my current directory
$cd .
$pwd
/home/guru/demo/dir1       <-  cd again to my current directory
cd ..
$pwd
/home/guru/demo           <-  cd  to parent directory
```